# How to convert generated-snippets .adoc files to html in src/docs/asciidoc using gradle project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin, asciidoc, spring-restdocs

I am facing the issue while working with the asciidoc for my spring rest docs implemetation my adoc files as per my test cases is created in **build/generated-snippets**.
I am having issue with creating html
where to create **src/docs/asciidoc** folder?
and which gradle task to run for that to build the html file if anyone knows anything about this isssue please reply as possible comments.

[My project explore looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9gdD.png)

Comment: Have you looked at the [REST Docs documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html5/) and [samples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html5/#getting-started-sample-applications)? There's a [section in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html5/#working-with-asciidoctor) that describes how to include the generated snippets in your Asciidoctor document.

Comment: Yes i have looked for the Documentation process as mentioned.

Comment: I am getting issue where to create the **src/docs/asciidoc** folder in my project for creating the html files of my .adoc files created in genrated-snippets folder.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you corectly, you could write another task that copies you docs to any folder you want.

```
task copyDoc(type: Copy) {
  dependsOn *test that creates docs*
  from *location of where docs are generated*
  into *where you want them to be*
}
```